# Force <T | null | undefined> type for function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

We are currently enforcing strict null checks on an older codebase and built ourselfes the helper

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined
```

We implemented a couple helper functions, they might look like this:

```js
function isSafe<T>(val: Maybe<T>): val is T {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3MKlOIBMIAzAS2IjoG4AoLx2gY2DMA9sSjMAzgGU4jVJgAUANzjkAXLATJ0GAJQaVVSXigBvLlCgAnCMFJWxhqAEJsuMpSgAyL1CevcWgYWNk4uAF8eAHoovAALY2MQiC5%20UQlgKDgNeCRUDKtWAHMsXAByYAgMsu5JGTkFOF1uLhj44wk44Qo6KAgrK2ErVPTMxA0C4pwoCqrgGq462QgFRGagA)

Works like a charm, an improvement that I would like though is, to prevent non-maybe values to be passed as a parameter, because with this typing, it would be possible to call `isSafe('hi')`, which can't be `null`, which is the case for every variable that is not wrapped in `Maybe`.

Preventing calls like that would move misunderstandings out of the way as I expect variables that are passed to `isSafe` to be `Maybe`.

Sadly I have not found a way to achieve this as `T | null | undefined` allows any of these types, rather than only the combination of these 3.

Is there a way to achieve a type error when passing a non-`Maybe` value to the function?
Bonus points would be if it also would allow `T | null` and `T | undefined` as we decided internally that we are going to handle both values the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which is a bit ugly, but meets your criteria:

```
type DefinitelyMaybe<T> = null extends T ? T : undefined extends T ? T : never

function isSafe<T>(val: DefinitelyMaybe<T>): val is NonNullable<typeof val> {
  return val !== null && val !== undefined;
}

// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
isSafe('test');

// OK
isSafe('test' as string | undefined);
```

Essentially, `DefinitelyMaybe<T>` is the same thing as `T` so long as either `null`, `undefined` or both are assignable to `T`. Otherwise, it's `never`, resulting in a type error at the call-site because the argument is not assignable to it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdo4EA2ICyBDEARhADwAqAfFALxTICuGGUEAHusgCYDOUpUA-LygAuKHU4IUEDszYROPPoL6jkEAG4QATgCgd8cQGNgiAPbIoiLgGVc8EhQAU63BlFwkqdFjyEH5AEpRFyYrKAA5c3CGDFwCDBJQSFN4KBDKAG8dKCgtCGA6LQsQqABCKhp6RigAMhq01zKKsQlPaQBuHQBfPQB6XqgAQS0AczoAW3lgKBSoJOgAci5gLRQRhcseZFNp3C4uRBHkOIS50ygwXC1cSfQtGdT5qAW1TS0FgDodK1t7RwX0MsFgE+gMAPIAaW+NjsEH+gOAGz2UGWq2QIygAB8WhxJGoOAFOkA)

Comment: It is fine if it is ugly in one place if it is prettier in other places :) Really smart solution though, thank you